# Need help changing background color of an item in a gridview - Android

Tags: android, gridview, setbackground

I currently have a gridview

```
GridView gv;
         gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
         gv.setNumColumns(RowsSplit[0].length());
         gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterClass(this, result));
```

result is an array of strings.

i want to then be able to change the background color of some of the items inside the grid.

```
for (int i : CorrectLetters)
{
    int temp2 = i;
    gv.getChildAt(temp2).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);        
}
```

CorrectLetters is an array of numbers that are the positions of the item in the grid that i want to change the colors of.

The error that I am getting is that when it gets to the foreach loop there are no children in the gridview so it throws a null exception error.

however if i put the foreach loop into the onclick event as should below it all works fine,

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
  {        
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {  
                    //do stuff here
                 }
   }
```

So my question is how can i get this foreach loop to work outside of the onclick listener?